# one iptables PREROUTING rule not work while other one works

Tags: iptables

I have a linux device with two iptables rules in it. And the behaviors are interesting.

```
root@xxx:~# iptables -t nat -nvL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 812 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REDIRECT   udp  --  *      *       10.20.40.10          0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:514 redir ports 5633
    0     0 REDIRECT   udp  --  *      *       10.20.40.15          0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:514 redir ports 5634
```

we already have rsyslog application listening on 514, we think iptables should take effect before rsyslog. but result became unexpected. for rule 1(10.20.40.10), we can confirm it is doing the job to redirect packet from 514 to 5633 since our application on 5633 got it. but for rule2(10.20.40.10), it is not doing the job. The packet directly goes to the application sitting on 514.

we plan to shut down rsyslog and take a look.

Any other good way or tools to troubleshooting this kind of issue? Really want to know the packet flow Thanks!

Comment: Add logging to the rules for better troubleshooting. Save the rules and check `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` for differences between the two rules.

Comment: Also, any reason not to just filter by source IP in rsyslog instead of redirecting with firewall rules? https://serverfault.com/a/400294/411612